# Is this short rate really constant?

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance, stochastic-calculus

Suppose that a financial instrument has a constant short-term rate $r$ and its price $S$ is driven by the equation

$$S_t = \mu_t S_t \, {\rm d}t,$$

where $(\mu_t$) is a process adapted to the natural filtration and for every $T<\infty$ we have

$$\mathsf P(\smallint\limits_0^T |\mu_t| \, {\rm d}t < \infty) = 1. $$

I want to show that $\mu_t = r$ for almost all $t$. Any hints how to do that?